# Display sortable Company column on the wp-admin All Users page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to display a sortable "Company" column on the wp-admin "All Users" page. I am using WooCommerce. I modified the code below and was able to add the "Company" column and make it sortable. I can populate the column with data using:

```
get_the_author_meta( 'user_firstname', $user ); // https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/
// I tried using company and user_company but they didn't work
```

get_the_author_meta works with many different values but I don't think it can pull company because company is a default field added by WooCommerce. My full code is below. How can I show company? Also, how do I change the order of these columns? I want to show Username, Name, Company, and Email in that order.

```
/*
 * Create a column & remove some of the default ones
 * @param array $columns Array of all user table columns {column ID} => {column Name} 
 */
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'rudr_modify_user_table' );

function rudr_modify_user_table( $columns ) {

    unset( $columns['role'] ); // Remove role column
    unset( $columns['posts'] ); // Remove posts column
    $columns['company'] = 'Company'; // Add new company column

    return $columns;

}

/*
 * Fill our new column with the company name of the users (if they have a company name in their profile)
 * @param string $row_output text/HTML output of a table cell
 * @param string $column_id_attr column ID
 * @param int $user user ID (in fact - table row ID)
 */
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'rudr_modify_user_table_row', 10, 3 );

function rudr_modify_user_table_row( $row_output, $column_id_attr, $user ) {

    switch ( $column_id_attr ) {
        case 'company' :
            // return get_the_author_meta( 'company', $user );
            // company is not included here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/
            // Need to use WooCommerce to find it but below is not working:
            return get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'company', true );
            break;
        default:
    }

    return $row_output;

}

/*
 * Make our "Company" column sortable
 * @param array $columns Array of all user sortable columns {column ID} => {orderby GET-param} 
 */
add_filter( 'manage_users_sortable_columns', 'rudr_make_company_column_sortable' );

function rudr_make_company_column_sortable( $columns ) {
    return wp_parse_args( array( 'company' => 'registered' ), $columns ); // This has an issue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- [request](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/request): you may need to use this filter in combination with `manage_users_sortable_columns`.

  ```
  add_filter( 'request', 'company_column_orderby' );
  //Add filter to the request to make the hits sorting process numeric, not string
  function company_column_orderby( $vars ) {
      if ( isset( $vars['orderby'] ) && 'company' == $vars['orderby'] ) {
          $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
              'meta_key' => 'company',
              'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
          ) );
      }
      return $vars;
  }

  add_filter( 'manage_users_sortable_columns', 'user_sortable_columns' );
  function user_sortable_columns( $columns ) {
       $columns['company'] = 'Company';
       return $columns;
  }
  ```